# Matching Timestamps and DatetimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working on a script for historians that allows them to compare data from different EXCEL tables with data input by the users running the scripts.

The users generally enter dates like this:

```
1765-04-05
```

The input by the users is then converted to DateTime in Pandas as follows:

```
year=input()
y = pd.to_datetime(year)
```

This creates a `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` and can be printed as:

```
Searching for events with exact date 1760-01-01 00:00:00 !
```

As no seconds, minutes or hours were indicated, they are obviously all `0`. Now we have got EXCEL tables with dates in YYYY-MM-DD format which also do not have hours, minutes or seconds. I am trying to convert them in analogy to the user input:

```
time=pd.to_datetime(f['event_start'].values)
```

When I check what the script is reading from the indicated column and what type it is, I get this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1739-01-01', '1740-01-01', '1741-01-01', '1742-01-01',
               '1744-01-01', '1752-01-01', '1753-01-01', '1755-01-01',
               '1756-01-01', '1757-01-01',
               ...
                      'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',
                      'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',
                      'NaT',        'NaT'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2228, freq=None)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'
```

So the type of the converted input and the type of the converted EXCEL values are not the same. What can I do to extract the time cells from EXCEL in a format that I can directly compare with the user input?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am aware that what comes from EXCEL is not a date but a string, which is why I am reading the values of the date column in excel into ```time=pd.to_datetime(f['event_start'].values)```. See above. The type is now a DatetimeIndex. But this cannot be compared to my Timestamps. So I either need to read the values in it as Timestamps, or to re-format the Timestamps I get from the user input. I am currently trying to apply ```to_datetime``` at a different stage of the script to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood, you are getting string from excels, which is not the same type as the `event_start` column of your dataframe, which, to me, actually seems fine! You can compare a NumPy array of `DatetimeIndex` with a string. Take the code below as an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
time = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1739-01-01', '1740-01-01', '1741-01-01', '1742-01-01',
               '1744-01-01', '1752-01-01', '1753-01-01', '1755-01-01',
               '1756-01-01', '1757-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
time == '1753-01-01'
```

which results in:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False])
```

As you can see, the seventh element comes True. If you are more interested in converting the string to an date object, I suggest you to use `dateutil.parser.parse` exactly as what follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse
time = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1739-01-01', '1740-01-01', '1741-01-01', '1742-01-01',
               '1744-01-01', '1752-01-01', '1753-01-01', '1755-01-01',
               '1756-01-01', '1757-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
time == parse(input('Enter a date string here: '))
```

Result:

```
Enter a date string here: 1755-01-01
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False])
```

Comment: Actually, I think my mis-conception was that I did not get that individual values in a DatetimeIndex ARE Timestamps, so what I tried reading from EXCEL was fine, I just need to be able to compare the individual values in the DatetimeIndex without loosing their link with other columns such as "person name" that I am querying at the some time. I guess I will need to re-write my script and re-phrase my question. But your answer was definitely helpful!